# create-two-separate-transactions-in-jpa-within-one-method-call spring boot jpa

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, boot, optimistic-concurrency

Hi I have issues with Transactions..

within single method
delete record by Id
and then update same record by Id

tried with single transaction and multiple transactions but not working ..
please suggests me how to handle
within Single Transaction perform Delete and update on same Entity.
else
within single method request two seperate Transactions.

tried with @Transactional class level , Method level and delete and update level.

but after deleting not able to update Entity.

and showing ERROR
HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements

Comment: If you delete the record then how can you update the record ehich does not exist?

Comment: @DhavalGajjar before delete store data in Collection..after delete data from Database..get collection and need to add same I'd 2 records and store again on database...same I'd like it's composite pk..

Comment: How ever issue resolved delete and update both runs in 2 different Transactions so now it's working..